# Azure DevOps predefined variables

Tags: powershell, variables, syntax, azure-devops

I need to use a predefined Azure DevOps variable in a release pipeline.
I'm working with several artifacts, and I need to get project name from each.

So, in an Inline PowerShell step, I try to use

> RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_{ARTEFACTNAME}_PROJECTNAME

But the interpolation doesn't work as wanted ..
I tried following without success:

```
$ProjectName = $("RELEASE.ARTIFACTS.$($var.name).PROJECTNAME")
```

Unfortunately, the result is always

> "RELEASE.ARTIFACTS.varname.PROJECTNAME" and not the ADO project name

Comment: IIRC, those variables are referenced `$(var.name)`.  It's not a subexpr.

Comment: Let me detail a bit more:

`$($var.name) = "REPOS1"
$(RELEASE.ARTIFACTS.REPOS1.PROJECTNAME) = PROJECT1
`

But, when I tried to get the value "PROJECT1" from my script by executing `$("RELEASE.ARTIFACTS.$($var.name).PROJECTNAME")`, I get result equals to "RELEASE.ARTIFACTS.varname.PROJECTNAME" instead of "PROJECT1"

Answer (score 1):

You may have to hard code the artifacts alias name in the expression.

```
#REPOS1 is the artifacts alias defined in release pipeline Artifacts-->Source alias

$ProjectName = $(Release.Artifacts.REPOS1.ProjectName)
```

You cannot wrap another `$()` inside `$()` like this `$(a.$(b).c)` in azure pipelines. Azure pipeline cannot resolve this kind expression $($()).

Below expressions will not work:

```
$alias = "Artifacts1"
$ProjectName = $(Release.Artifacts.$($alias).ProjectName)

$ProjectName = $(Release.Artifacts.$(arifactName).ProjectName)
```

Comment: My problem is that I have several artifacts, that's why I have to build it in PowerShell.

Comment: how were the artifacts added to your release pipeline. Are them added separately or in one artifacts. When you add a artifacts, you can define its alias name in the Source alias field, which you can use to identify them. Could share a screenshot?

Comment: Is it the case that you have to decide the alias name by some kind of condition in the powershell task?

Comment: @gerem even if you have multiple artifacts if you do not add them dynamically you have fixed number of them. I know that this is not the best approach, but from what we see here it is the best approach we can have. I also tried to find better approach, but it must be like Levi Ls-MSFT says.